# Batch: compare files using CRC32

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, compare, crc32

I have given myself a simple task of writing a batch file that will do the following:

Compare CRC32 of each file in "first" folder with each file in "second" folder. Output needs to be the name of every file from the "first" folder, which doesn't have its duplicate in "second".

Note: "CRC32.exe  -nf" outputs CRC32 in first line, and file size in second one.

Here is how I tried to do it:

```
@echo off

for %%i in ("%cd%\first\*.*") do (
    set uniq=0
    for /f %%x in ('crc32 %%i -nf') do (
        set one=%%x
        goto find_two
    )
    :find_two
    for %%j in ("%cd%\second\*.*") do (
        for /f %%x in ('crc32 %%j -nf') do (
            set two=%%x
            goto compare
        )
        :compare
        if one==two (
            goto next
        ) else (
            set uniq=1
        )
    )
    if uniq==1 (
        echo %%i >>result.txt
    )
    :next
)
```

I assume there are several errors present in this code, but I had trouble finding them. So if anyone has time, and thinks he can help, I would be grateful.

If you think different approach is required, feel free to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major problems.

Goto's inside brackt doesn't work as expected, they stop the loop immediately, so your code will simply fail there.
The solution is to avoid `goto` or to call a function and use the `goto` there.

The second problem are the compares.
`if one==two (` will be always false, as it compare the word `one` against the word `two`, but not the content of the variables.

Normally you would use `if "%one%"=="%two%" echo equal`, but as it should work inside of brackets you need delayed expansion, so it looks like.

```
if !one!==!two! echo equal
```

Don't forget to enable the delayed expansion before you start the loop with

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Comment: The only reason I used `goto` is because there is no `break` like there is in C++, but I didn't know that it will not only break the nested loop, but all of them. I have modified the script according to your instructions and now it looks like this: [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=efbhNmV7). But I still get the same error as before: "_) was not expected at this time._"

Comment: Thank you for your help jeb. Thanks to you I realized that breaking out of nested loop was the main problem, I searched around and found how to do it. This is how the code looks now, and it works as intended: [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=a1Bsm1TK)

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to capture the output of crc32 using something like this:

```
for /f %%x in ('crc32 "%filename%" -nf ^| find /v "CRC32"') do stuff with %%x
```

Can you show me the full output of an example crc32 if this is not helpful?